# App Inventor 2 - Separating numbers

Tags: app-inventor

In my app I will have several lines of numbers from 4 to 10
characters in length. How would I go around separating the generated
numbers every 3 numbers (at thousand, million, billion).

I will not know the length of the numbers beforehand so the same .text
label can sometimes be longer or shorter.

e.g. from `1234567` `12345` `1234567890`

to `1,234,567` `12,345` `1,234,567,890`

The separators can be a space, a dot or a comma (any is fine). I am
quite familiar with AI2 but can't figure this one out.

EDIT: Seems like I managed to segment the text (yay!)
[image]

What would I have to do now if I have let's say 10 labels with all different lengths? It would be extremely excessive to check length of each label using an `if` and then segmenting it using corresponding length option. Is there a way to shorten the process?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own custom procedure, for example [see the following **App Inventor Classic** example](https://puravidaapps.com/snippets1.php#thousand), which uses a `for range` loop:

The algorithm works like this (example=2134256):
result after first loop: **,256**
result after second loop: **,134,256**
then add the remaining digits of the number, in this case **2**
result in the end: **2,134,256**

[image: Y]

**Edit**: For App Inventor 2, you also have to use a `procedure with result`. Also let me recommend to use a local variable `result` instead of a global variable.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Taifun, since the example is in AI Classic I came across an issue when converting to AI2. When I use the standard procedure I cannot get any result at the end, on the other hand when I use the procedure with result I don't really know how to fit the `for each` block. How would I go around to recieve the result? [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/1B9ut)

Comment: Thank you very much, works perfect now! Here is a [SCREENSHOT](http://imgur.com/GyUeGLl) of the final blocks in AI2 as someone might find it useful in the future (as well as if you want to update the tutorial with AI2 version).